# Proving that a plaintext is the Paillier decryption of a certain ciphertext

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, paillier

Assume that Alice received 100 ciphertexts encrypted with additive homomorphic encryption, say Paillier, using the same public key that belongs to Bob.
Alice added all of them, and wants to know the final sum, so she sends the final result (which is still encrypted of course) to Bob so that he can decrypt it with his private key, and return the result of the sum in clear text to Alice.

How can Alice be sure that Bob didn't give her a number that doesn't match her encrypted sum?

Should I use another additively homomorphic encryption if I want ZKP?

Comment: Does Bob need to know the answer?

Comment: I am assuming that there's no risk with Bob knowing the answer, but he doesn't need to know it.

Comment: Very related to [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6467/questions-about-proof-of-correct-encryption-in-the-paillier-cryptosystem).

Comment: I was actually mislead by that question, and that's why I added "r". I have now deleted it because I want the opposite. He wants a proof that the encryption was done right, while I need a proof that the decryption was done right. I don't know if there's a way to get the "r" from the ciphertext.

Comment: In my paradigm, Bob doesn't know anything about the original 100 ciphertexts that were encrypted using his public key. Alice wants to know the sum without compromising the privacy of those that submitted the ciphertexts.

Comment: [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6732/how-to-verify-a-number-encrypted-with-an-unknown-key/) is also related.

Comment: On recovering $r$, see [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3290/several-questions-about-paillier-cryptosystem)

Comment: Obviously I don't know your exact application domain. But, if Alice knows something about the possible plaintexts (e.g., if it is a voting system, Alice should know approximately how many votes to expect for each candidate due to polling, etc), she should add a random value to the summed ciphertexts. Bob does the decryption, Alice subtracts the random value to get the answer.

If Bob tries to cheat, he doesn't know the random value, so, with high probability, alice is left with a random value, which won't match what is expected.

Comment: The first link is also useful, but in my case Alice doesn't know the plaintexts, so she doesn't know "r"s. She would need to ask everybody to send their "r"s along with their encrypted number, which is not so practical, if even secure. Regarding your last comment, my application is similar to voting in essence but it's summing matrices at Alice from many people. Alice shouldn't know them, but she is allowed to know the final sum after receiving the decryption from Bob. In this case, I'm only considering Bob to be malicious; hence the need to verify Bob will decrypt the sum correctly.